# check tag sequence in xml database export with word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a problem with a macro i am writing. I need to convert an export file from a database (glossary) into another tag structure to be able to import it in another database.

I did almost all the steps but what i am having troubles in doing is what follows. Most of the entries are bilingual. however, some entries have more than one value (maximum of 3) English entries.

Therefore, i need to check the tag sequence, and if a double English entry is found, convert it into two entries. This is done.

The problem is that even when the macro finds a "correct" entry, instead of ignoring it and jumping to the next one, it tries to modify it as if it was wrong.

Here is the macro code:

```
Sub CheckTagSequence()
'DECLARATION OF VARIABLES
Dim textline As String
Dim SourceLang, TargetLang, EntryID As String
Dim i As String
Dim objWdRange As String

'ASSIGNING VALUES TO THE VARIABLES
SourceLang = "<enTerm>"
TargetLang = "<frTerm>"
i = "<entry id="">"

'GO TO FIRST LINE
Selection.GoTo what:=gotoline, which:=GoToFirst
' MOVE DOWN TWO LINES
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
CONTINUA:
If Left(textline, 8) = i Then ID = textline
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
If Left(textline, 8) = "<subject" Then su = textline
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
If Left(textline, 8) = SourcLang Then en = textline
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
**If Left(textline, 8) = TargetLang Then fr = textline
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
If Left(textline, 8) = "</entry>" Then**
Selection.GoTo CONTINUA
ElseIf Left(textline, 8) = SourceLang Then GoTo CORREGGI
End If

CORREGGI:
Selection.MoveUp unit:=wdLine, Count:=3
Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdLine
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Selection.Paste
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy
Selection.MoveUp unit:=wdLine, Count:=3
Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdLine
Selection.Paste
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
If Left(textline, 8) = i Then GoTo CONTINUA
End Sub
```

It blocks at these lines:

```
If Left(textline, 8) = TargetLang Then fr = textline
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
If Left(textline, 8) = "</entry>" Then
Selection.GoTo CONTINUA
```

And here is the content of a sample file:

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8”?>
<body>
<entry id=““>
<subject>IRECRUITMENT</subject>
<enTerm>Media Relations</enTerm>
<frTerm>Relations avec les médias</frTerm>
</entry>
<entry id=““>
<subject>IRECRUITMENT</subject>
<enTerm>OCEM</enTerm>
<frTerm>Relations avec les médias</frTerm>
</entry>
<entry id=““>
<subject>IRECRUITMENT</subject>
<enTerm>STATISTICS</enTerm>
<enTerm>FIPSS</enTerm>
<frTerm>STATISTIQUES</frTerm>
</entry>
<entry id=““>
<subject>IRECRUITMENT</subject>
<enTerm>3rd Nationality</enTerm>
<frTerm>3ème nationalité</frTerm>
</entry>
<entry id=””>
<subject>IRECRUITMENT</subject>
<enTerm>FINANCE</enTerm>
<enTerm>CSSDF</enTerm>
<frTerm>FINANCES</frTerm>
</entry>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't attempt this the way you are going about it, or even the way I am going to suggest here. I'd probably try to read the text into an MSXML object and manipulate the XML tree in there, then write it back. But if your data is as simple as you describe, you only have  and  elements to deal with, and you can only have 1, 2 or 3  elements, then I think the following code will work and will show you another way that you can begin to approach this kind of task. However, if your actual data is more complex, there will still be quite a lot of work to do.

I make some comments after the code.

```
Sub reorgEntries()
Const strFindEnTerm As String = "(\<enTerm\>*\</enTerm\>^13)"
Dim i As Integer
Dim rngContent As Word.Range
Dim rngEntry As Word.Range
Dim strFIndEntry As String
Dim strFindEnTerms(2) As String
Dim strReplaceEnTerms(2) As String
' Finds a complete entry
strFIndEntry = "^13\<entry*\</entry\>"
' First find and replace entries with 3 En terms
strFindEnTerms(1) = "(^13*)" & strFindEnTerm & strFindEnTerm & strFindEnTerm & "(*\</entry\>)"
strReplaceEnTerms(1) = "\1\2\5\1\3\5\1\4\5"
' Then with 2 terms
strFindEnTerms(2) = "(^13*)" & strFindEnTerm & strFindEnTerm & "(*\</entry\>)"
strReplaceEnTerms(2) = "\1\2\4\1\3\4"
For i = 1 To 2
  Call ClearFindAndReplaceParameters
  Set rngContent = ActiveDocument.Range
  With rngContent.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = strFIndEntry
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    While .Execute ' (Replace:=WdReplace.wdReplaceNone)
      Set rngEntry = rngContent.Duplicate
      With rngEntry.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = strFindEnTerms(i)
        .Replacement.Text = strReplaceEnTerms(i)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        While .Execute(Replace:=WdReplace.wdReplaceOne)
        Wend
      End With
      Set rngEntry = Nothing
    Wend
  End With
  Set rngContent = Nothing
Next
End Sub

Sub ClearFindAndReplaceParameters()

' You may need this to make wildcard searches
' work properly after a failed wildcard search
' (there is/was an error in Word)
With Selection.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = ""
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Format = False
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

End Sub
```

As you can tell, the code uses Word's Find/Replace methods to do the replacement, and specifically uses wildcard matching. This is similar to using "regex" or "regular expressions", but Word's builtin regular expression syntax is different (and generally more unhelpful) from most other regex dialects. If you are unfamiliar with regex, it may take some time to understand how this works, but you can do an internet search for articles about Word's regex and work it out. The main thing is that the "()" group the regex into numbered parts, and when you replace by "\1\2\4\1\3\4" you are replacing the found text with parts 1, 2 and 4, then parts 1, 3 and 4.

To make the regex expressions simpler the code loops looking for "Entries", then processes each Entry. Searching only for entries with more than one enTerm element is considerably harder - in fact I am not even sure it is possible in Word's regex dialect. If someone has a regex that works, I hope they'll tell us.

Unfortunately, this particular code is already at its limits - if you had to search for 4 EnTerms as well, you could not simply extend it because you can only specify 10 repelacmeent parts in the Replace string.

Because you also have to consider what happens to the Ranges after you make a replacement, it was simpler in this case to make two complete passes through the text.

Now, just some comments on the code you posted here in case you would prefer to try to fix that.

- You don't set textline (you would need to set it to Selection.Text or
  possibly Selection.Paragraphs(1).Text )
- You would need to compare Left(textline,8) with Left(i,8) rather than
  with i
- I think you would probably need Goto CONTINUA rather than
  Selection.Goto CONTINUA
- As a matter of programming style, it's better to try to avoid Goto
  statements. Apart from anything else, it becomes very hard for people
  to understand what you are actually trying to achieve.

Finally, the variable name "i" is usually used as an integer variable, especially as a loop counter and so on. For a temporary string, some people would use "s" . Others would always use a longer name such as strEntry.